# SLI on CrossFire Motherboard, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, "Insufficient PCIe link width"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am currently trying to set up SLI on my Ubuntu PC, using two GIGABYTE GTX 970 4GB and a 2 way SLI bridge.

I have a Crossfire motherboard (16x PCIE and 4x) and I want to SLI them, and I know it is possible from this guide: https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/sli.html,

here is the quote which makes me believe it is possible:

> The PCI Express slots on the motherboard must provide a minimum link width. Please make sure that the PCI Express slot(s) on your
> motherboard meet the following requirements and that you have
> connected the graphics board to the correct PCI Express slot(s):
>
> A dual-GPU board needs a minimum of 8 lanes (i.e. x8 or x16)
>
> A pair of single-GPU boards requires one of the following supported link width combinations:
>
> ```
> x16 + x16
>
> x16 + x8
>
> x16 + x4
>
> x8 + x8
> ```

Unfortunately, when I enable sli in nvidia-xconfig (nvidia-xconfig --sli=on), on reboot, in Xorg.0.log this error appears:

```
[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to find a valid SLI configuration.

[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Invalid SLI configuration 1 of 1:

[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): GPUs:

[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 1) NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0

[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 2) NVIDIA GPU at PCI:6:0:0

[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Errors:

[ 8.138] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): - Insufficient PCIe link width

[ 8.138] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to find a valid SLI configuration for the NVIDIA

[ 8.138] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): graphics device PCI:1:0:0. Please see Chapter 30:

[ 8.138] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Configuring SLI and Multi-GPU FrameRendering in the README

[ 8.138] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): for troubleshooting suggestions.

[ 8.176] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Only one GPU will be used for this X screen.
```

From lspci I know that one of the cards (at PCI:1:0:0) has the Link Status at:

```
LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
```

and Link Capabilities at:

```
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
```

while the second one, (at PCI6:0:0) has the same link capabilities, but link status at:

```
LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x4, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
```

So from what I gather, the speed and link width is mismatched for the second card and if I understand this correctly, I need to change the link width and then speed. **If that is correct, how can I do that, or what can I do to make it work otherwise?**

My specifications:

Motherboard: ASUS M5A97 PRO

CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor

GPUs:

```
[connected to PCIe 2.0 x16_1 slot (at 16x mode)] GIGABYTE GTX 970 4GB

[connected to PCIe 2.0 x16_1 slot (at 4x mode)] GIGABYTE GTX 970 4GB
```